# Offline Web App, Application Cache, Ipad iOS6, and HTTPS, HTML5

Tags: html, ipad, caching, ios6, manifest

I am writing a web application that is meant to me utilized "sometimes" offline using the iPad's home bookmarked feature of Safari . By "sometimes", I mean that the app should work if the iPad is offline and data has been cached. If the iPad is online and the cache manifest has changed, the app should update the contents of the cache.  The web page is protected through https.

Currently, I can get my app to work correctly using Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. I have tested them all in windows 7 and windows XP. The app also works correctly in the iPad's "normal" way of using Safari, but when I run the bookmarked version of the app (created by specifying the special standalone apple metas and then bookmarking) it does the initial password prompt and correctly moves on to download all the data specified in the cache manifest file. The trouble is that any subsequent runs of the standalone app do not seem to have access to the manifest file and thus any later updates to the manifest file do not get reflected.

So my question is this: does HTML5 specific caching work on the iPad (ios6) with https on a stand alone (bookmarked) web app?

Comment: No takers? It's driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

[Application Caching on iPad will not cache website data or pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002355/application-caching-on-ipad-will-not-cache-website-data-or-pages)

I was having the same problem. This answer worked. Hope it does for you too!